# Mongoose populate not working in javascript when Schema is ReadOnly

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Consider we have two microservices,
MS1 => Schema Defined
MS2 => Use the Schema as readonly

When the readonly Schema. Populate is not working.
But populate is working in MS1 not in MS2

microservice 1

```
const accountSchema = new Schema({ user:{ type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } })
```

microservice 2

```
//readOnly Schema.
const accountSchema = new Schema({}, { strict: false });

export const AccountModel = model('accounts', accountSchema);
```

```
const account = await AccountModel.findById(${id}).populate(user) 

console.info(account) //undefinded
```

```
expecting Result

account = { 
   User: {},
   ... 
   accountinfo
 }
```